# Aurelia no such file or directory aurelia-fetch-client.js

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm a beginner of Aurelia and learning to put code pieces together.

itemWithPicture.js

```
import "fetch";
import {HttpClient, json} from "aurelia-fetch-client";

let httpClient = new HttpClient();

export class ItemWithPicture {
    constructor() {
        this.heading = "Item with Picture";
    }
}
```

The error I got is

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\GitRepo\pictureRecord\n
ode_modules\aurelia-fetch-client.js']
     errno: -4058,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: 'C:\\GitRepo\\pictureRecord\\node_modules\\aurelia-fetch-client.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'itemWithPicture' ],
     fileName: 'C:/GitRepo/pictureRecord/src/itemWithPicture.js' },
  duration: [ 0, 2993168 ],
  time: 1470835605761 }
```

Comment: I figured out the problem. Need to add "es7.decorators" under config.js for babeloptions.

Comment: Please post your comment as the answer to your question, so that others can more easily find it and also upvote it if it's useful for them :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you use the Aurelia CLI to create your project, install with npm aurelia-fetch-client.

```
$ npm install aurelia-fetch-client --save
```

*if you use a base Unix system (mac or linux), i think in windows may be the same command.*

After, inside your poject, in the folder **aurelia_project** in the *file aurelia.json* add these lines:

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-fetch-client",
  "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-fetch-client/dist/amd",
  "main": "aurelia-fetch-client"
}
```

In my case, i put inside the tags bundle eg.

```
"bundles": [
        {
           ...
        },
        {
            "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
             ...,
            "dependencies": [
                ...
                {
                    "name": "aurelia-fetch-client",
                    "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-fetch-client/dist/amd",
                    "main": "aurelia-fetch-client"
               } ...
```

Or something like that.

Comment: I used that way.. Now that error is gone and have this one... [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/chanaka/WebstormProjects/kaishr/src/fetch.js']

Answer (score 4):

First you need to npm install aurelia-fetch-client.
After that, you need to go into the aurelia_project/aurelia.json file and add the following to the dependencies section:

"aurelia-fetch-client"

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I have no idea why they didn't add this to the documentation in the first place.